# SQL Server for xml path with double elements

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, for-xml-path

I'm trying to create a xml output in SQL Server 2012 using FOR XML PATH.
What can be done to get the desired output?

**I would like to output to be:**

```
<types>
    <type>
        <type>FirstType</type>
        <attribute>FirstAttribute</attribute>
    </type>
</types>
<types>
    <type>
        <type>SecondType</type>
        <attribute>SecondAttribute</attribute>
    </type>
</types>
<types>
    <type>
        <type>ThirdType</type>
        <attribute>ThirdAttribute</attribute>
    </type>
</types>
```

**My code:**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
type VARCHAR(50)
, attribute VARCHAR(50)
)

SELECT T1.type
, T1.attribute
FROM @table AS T1
FOR XML path('type'), root('types')
```

**Gives me wrong output:**

```
<types>
    <type>
        <type>FirstType</type>
        <attribute>FirstAttribute</attribute>
    </type>
    <type>
        <type>SecondType</type>
        <attribute>SecondAttribute</attribute>
    </type>
    <type>
        <type>ThirdType</type>
        <attribute>ThirdAttribute</attribute>
    </type>
</types>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple roots in a valid xml document. If you are declaring `<types>` multiple times, then it's not your root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns what you want:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
[type] VARCHAR(50)
, attribute VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES('FirstType','FirstAttribute')
                        ,('SecondType','SecondAttribute')

SELECT T1.type AS [type/type]
, T1.attribute AS [type/attribute]
FROM @table AS T1
FOR XML path('types');
```

But be warned: It is invalid due to the missing root node. SQL-Server's XML engine can deal with this, but other engines might fail...

I think, SQL Server is not so strict, as - very often - XML is built out of several fragments. And such a result could be one of these fragments without any problems...

Comment: Exactly, that is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to output to be:
>
> ```
> <types>
> <type>
>     <type>FirstType</type>
>     <attribute>FirstAttribute</attribute>
> </type> </types> <types>
> <type>
>     <type>SecondType</type>
>     <attribute>SecondAttribute</attribute>
> </type> </types> <types>
> <type>
>     <type>ThirdType</type>
>     <attribute>ThirdAttribute</attribute>
> </type> 
> </types>
> ```

Your desired output is not even well-formed XML:

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp
Line Number 7, Column 1:
<types>
^
```

You cannot have multiple root elements.

Comment: Well, in general it's invalid XML, but SQL-Server can deal with this...